# HLOOKUP With Date Returning #REF

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a value in row 101 based on a date in row 2 in the range specified below. I am looking for a date with a variable month - the month number is in cell B110.  I feel like this should work, but it keeps returning #REF!

Any suggestions? Thank you :)

```
=HLOOKUP(DATE(2022,B110,1), N2:NN101, 101, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have N2:NN101 then the number of rows is 101 - 1 = 100

As row 1 is not included.

So the row_index_num ie the 3rd argument should be 100 if you want the last row.

Comment: Using 99 was one row too little - I changed it to 100 and it worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works, yes see my error now - will edit.